# Spray not setting Content-Type header for FormData

Tags: scala, spray, spray-client

`FormData` is supposed to set the `Content-Type` header automatically but it isn't working. So I tried to set it manually but I get a warning.

```
val gzipPipeline: HttpRequest => Future[HttpResponse] = encode(Gzip) ~> sendReceive ~> decode(Gzip)

val request =
      (Post(uri,
        FormData(Map(
          "set_login" -> credentials.username,
          "set_pass" -> credentials.password))
      ) ~> addHeader(`Content-Type`(`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`))
        ~> addHeader(`Accept-Encoding`(gzip)))

[WARN] [04/14/2016 02:09:50.803] [forPipeline-akka..default-dispatcher-8] [akka://forPipeline/user/IO-HTTP/group-0/0] Explicitly set request header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' is ignored, the request Content-Type is set via the request's HttpEntity!
```

In either case, the response I get from the server is the response that I get when I don't set the `Content-Type` header.

Have I constructed the pipeline and `HttpEntity` properly? Am I supposed to use a marshaller for `FormData`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set the `HttpRequest` properly but the server does not accept gzip-encoded requests. I just had to remove gzip encoding from the pipeline.